# Switch router and attrs while drawing a link in joints

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm using manhattan route for my links:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    //...
    defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({
        router: { name: 'manhattan' },
        connector: { name: 'rounded' },
        attrs: {
            '.marker-target': { d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z', fill: '#6a6c8a', stroke: '#6a6c8a' },
            '.connection': { stroke: '#6a6c8a', 'stroke-width': 2 }
        }
    })
});
```

Now I would like to use a simple direct arror link while drawing a link from one port to another port.

```
paper.on({
    'cell:pointerdown': function(cellView, event) {
        cellView.model.set('router', { name: 'orthogonal' });
        // ... and define link style, like  dashed line...
    },
    'cell:pointerup': function(cellView, event) {
        //switch back to defaultLink-style
    }
});
```

But this doesn't have an effect at all.